# Windows 10 wireless card cannot ping local network: "Destination host unreachable"

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

I have Windows 10 running on a PC I built within the past month. I've had no trouble with the wifi until today. My wireless appears connected but I can't ping any location except localhost.

I've gone through a bunch of `ipconfig` steps, rebooted the router and the PC, uninstalled/reinstalled the network drivers, etc.

When I ping another machine on my local network, I see:

```
Pinging 172.168.1.181 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.168.1.156: Destination host unreachable
```

I've tried to release/renew the ip, I've thrown `net stop/start` in the middle, but I'm still assigned the same IP every time.

No other computer on my network has this problem.

Setting a static IP on the windows box (confirmed with ipconfig) results in the same message as above, just with the new IP.

Comment: Can you connect to the internet or outside of your local network, or is it unable to reach anywhere?

Comment: Every once in a while I can ping my router but if I try any more traffic than a ping it dies. When I can't ping my router, pings outside of the router fail as well.

Comment: "I use a VPN that (stupidly) uses 192.168.x.x so I had to change my local range to distinguish them."  Does this problem exist only while the VPN is active?

Comment: No, and the VPN is software-based and not used from this computer.